# Error when importing CSV files into pandas

Tags: csv, pandas, python-3.4

I am trying to import a single CSV, but I'm getting the following error:
"pandas.parser.CParserError: Erro tokenizing data. C errorL Expeceted 1 fields in line 4, saw 16"
This is the code I'm running
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb

```
 Location = (r'path')
 df = (read_csv(Location))
 print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the error by adding using. df = (read_csv(Location, skiprows=1))